# Outlook 2010 Inbox folder deleted but it is still trying to archive it

Tags: archive, outlook

One of my users has dozens of PST files, one for each project he is working on. He has a folder for each under the inbox, and once a project is finished, he has archived the rest of the files in that folder and then deletes the folder. The problem is that when he runs the auto-archive, it keeps opening the PST files related to those missing folders, although obviously nothing is added to them. I know I can tell Auto-Archive to not show the folder in the list, but that's not really the point. Where does outlook store this list and is it editable, because this is going to start happening more and more here.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your user closes that specific PST project file (removes data file for that project in account settings).

Comment: Hi Adam,
Yes, he does close the PST file, and has also deleted the inbox subfolder that was set to archive to that specific PST file (generalizing because he has about 20 of these folders in a 1 to 1 relationship with a PST file). The problem is when he runs auto-archive and chooses 'archive all folders based on their settings' it re-opens the PST file, so I know that somewhere in the bowels of Windows, there is a list that has all the archive instructions.

Comment: I've tried to recreate the issue however my Autoarchive never reopened any PST... Have you tried to test the situation with one of these reopening PST moved away from the folder they reside? Any errors showing up?